# How to perform static program analysis in Python for finding functions with certain properties?

Tags: python, static-code-analysis

For a given, arbitrary Python file, I want to find and isolate all function with the properties that:

1. It takes a `str` literal as an argument
2. It returns a `str` literal as an output
3. The function is self-contained; it does not depend on global variables or variables/objects in external classes

How should I do this in Python in a scalable way? I'm not looking to go through the file and add types myself.

Comment: @Sanyash Yes. I'd also be interested in learning how to do this in general for a restriction on arbitrary types.

Comment: Third property seems to be impossible to be verified in complex cases.

Comment: For first and second properties you can annotate your code like this: `def foo(arg: str) -> str:`. After that it will be not so difficult to find such annotated functions.

Comment: @Sanyash I'm sorry, but your answers are not helpful; I am assuming that this is code from a third-party (i.e., not my own) and I want to be able to do this automatically in a scalable way.

Comment: In this case AFAIK there is no way to do it.

Comment: @Sanyash AFAIK, this is a typical problem that is solved with SCA software (so not an impossible problem), but I need help getting started. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I mean, no way in Python due to it's dynamic typing nature.

Comment: @Prune I think my question was fine, but thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Python 3.7 with [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). But you'll need to provide type annotations on the function.

A simple example is:

```py
import typing

def main(hello: str, world: int): -> typing.List[int]:
    x = list(range(world)
    print(x)
    return x

typing.get_type_hints(main)
>>> {'hello': str, 'world': int, 'return': typing.List[int]}
```

This **does not enforce** that the function actually uses those types, but it does make introspection easier. [Mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) can enforce that the function works with the annotated types.

Edit: Google has a project called infers function types called [pytype](https://github.com/google/pytype). It's not perfect, but it can be a quick way to add some mypy annotations to a third party package.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for putting together an answer. But I suppose I could have been more clear in my question; I want to inspect third-party code, which presumably does not have type annotation, and see which functions have the properties that I asked for.

Comment: I'm looking to do this on many different files in an automatic and scalable fashion.